# Run Javascript function after postback in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, postback

I have a button which causes a postback and also calls the javascript function hideInsert() which looks something like this:

```
function hideInsert() {
    $('.hide').hide();
        alert("hide");
    }
```

All it does is hiding tablerows marked with ".hide". This works as intended but since the postback occurs, everything gets reset.

Is there anyway I can click the button to trigger the postback and then run the function, after the postback has occurred?

I have been looking at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx but with no success.

I would then need to press another button which would trigger the showInsert() function, which would need a similar function.

Comment: RegisterStartupScript is what I would have suggested.. What about that isn't working?

Comment: You would need to write your script directly into the page from your codebehind. Not in a function of course, so that it executes immediately. Of course you could aswell hide the controls from your codebehind too...

Comment: I believe `Page.IsPostBack` will be of help to you. You might want to give us more detail as to what your problem is exactly. Are you calling the function and then postback occurs?

Comment: I was overthinking this, Bartdude. Of course the simple solution was to hide the controls with .visible = false in the C# code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In whatever event makes most sense according to your current architecture, include:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack) {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "HideOnPostback", "$(function() { hideInsert(); })", true); 
}
```

`Page_Load` is a common place to include logic like this.

Alternatively, if you will never need whatever is classed as `.hide` after they postback and they are server-side controls, you could always set them to `Visible = false`.